# Search Data from Database and Display in unbound but predefined column Datagridview VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

i want to search data from SQL database and display in pre defined columns of datagridview. following code i used for that:-

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    qry = "select * from Transs where DocNo='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read Then

        ComboBox1.Text = dr("CostCenter")
        TextBox2.Text = dr("TransactionID")
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = dr("AccountID")
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dr("AccountName")
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = dr("AccountType")
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dr("Debit")
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dr("Credit")
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = dr("Text")
    End If
Next
con.Close()
```

But the problem is i am getting data in first row of datagridview only. Where is the mistake in this code?

Comment: Your loop is inverted (you need loop the DataReader results, not the DataGridView Rows) -- Remove `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` -- Create a DataTable, load it with `DataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())`, then assign the DataTable to the DataSource of both the DataGridView and the ComboBox and set its the DisplayMmeber to "CostCenter". Add a DataBinding to the TextBox, binding `Text` and `TransactionID`. Use Command Parameters, remove string concatenation. Declare your Connection in place and dispose of it after use along with the Command. Double-check whether `DocNo` is a string type [... More ...].

Comment: Are there already rows in the DataGridView before you run this code? What is the datatype of DocNo in the database? Why would you execute the same query over and over in a loop? Do you expect the value of TextBox1.Text to change while you are looping?

Comment: If you are required to run the query in the loop, use parameters over string concatenation to build your sql command.  You will get quite a performance boost.  As Mary suggested though, appears that your sql is static within the context of the loop, so safe to move it outside of the loop